# Is there any app for Stack Exchange?

Tags: google-play-store

Is there any app available in the Android Market for Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: A good resource to find the currently state of art Android App for Stackexchange is [the highest voted android tag Q&A on stackapps](http://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/android?sort=votes&pagesize=15). Droidstack isn't really maintained any more.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a couple of apps out there like [Droidstack](https://stackapps.com/questions/585/droidstack-for-android-1-0-8b) and [StackWidget](https://stackapps.com/questions/821/stackwidget-for-android).  Both of the apps can work together.  I've just installed them, but so far you can't seem to answer or respond to questions with them.  You can though, follow your questions and get notifications when you get answers.   Droidstack is a question browser, and StackWidget lets you watch specific questions.

There is also [TopStack](https://stackapps.com/questions/979/topstack-android-client-for-stack-exchange) for question browsing and [SOflair](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/social/soflair_nuy.html) for reputation monitoring.  Having tried them.

Comment: The SOAPI doesn't allow write access at the moment so no app will allow you answer questions. Go for droidstack.

Comment: Droidstack only notifies me of rep changes. Shouldn't it notify me when I get mentioned, when my question is answered, etc?

Comment: @Bruce currently the "inbox" is not available yet to the API, but will be in version 2.0.  Version 3.0 will include write access via API.

Comment: @Bryan Cool. Is there an expected date for the new versions?

Comment: @Bruce roadmap here: http://stackapps.com/questions/1999/announcing-api-version-1-1 No schedule/expected dates yet

Answer (score 26):

The [**official Stack Exchange app**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here/) is now [available in the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin).

Comment: The best answer

Comment: And [David uses](http://i.stack.imgur.com/u0sWL.png) it proudly.

Comment: Note: the app has been [removed from the Play Store since 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353133/241919) and [its infrastructure has been removed since 2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383026/241919).

Answer (score 12):

There just happens to be such a tool. It's not an actual application, but it works quite well with and is optimized for Android phones and tablets.

#### Website: [StackMobile.com](http://stackmobile.com/beta)

[image]

Some of the features you will find:

- Full access to all questions, answers, comments, and users on the site.
- Full question and user search capability.
- The ability to easily switch between StackMobile and the equivalent page on the main site.
- View tags and tag wiki excerpts as well as questions with certain tags.
- View user profiles including a user's top 5 question / answers.
- The ability to quickly share pages using social network buttons.

**Disclaimer:** I wrote it.

Answer (score 11):

[DroidStack](https://stackapps.com/questions/585/droidstack-for-android-1-0-8) seems to be the ticket.  [*Android Market Link*](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.droidstack)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It would be great if its directly available from app store.

Comment: That's where I downloaded it from; sorry, I have a helluva time linking to pages in the AndroidMarket..... hrm... that remind me

Answer (score 3):

There is a site specifically for apps that use the Stack Exchange API(s): [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/).

If you're looking for Stack Exchange apps for Android, simply look under the [android](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/android) tag there.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the opportunity to try [Stack Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.b5d.android&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5iNWQuYW5kcm9pZCJd), which features an incredibly well-designed interface that looks really slick:

[image]
[image]
[image]

As is the case with all other apps that use the latest version of the API (2.1 at the time of this writing), there is no support for asking and answering questions. However, the app is handy for checking your inbox and quickly browsing questions.