# App to ask question on stackexchange?

Tags: applications

Is there any application to ask question on stackexchange as well, instead of just monitoring a user timeline to get notifications?

Comment: There is [this related question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/338/is-there-any-app-for-stackexchange), but it and its answers deal with reading and don't offer any solutions for asking questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but there is an effort underway to improve the mobile versions of the Stack Exchange sites.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98215/stack-exchange-mobile-theme-beta-starts-now

I have used my Android browser to interact with the Stack Exchange sites and it works pretty well.

Comment: Your link is invalid

Comment: @LifeH2O: I guess they removed it. I've linked to the current discussion. The changes are apparently live on all sites.

Answer (score 6):

There is "[DroidStack](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.droidstack&feature=search_result)" which allows to Browse the Questions, Users, Tags and Monitor for Statuschanges, but it does not allow you to question yourself or write an answer. But you can open the current question, user, whatever in your favorite browser anytime. This comes closest to writing.

There are other tools, with similar restrictions, but I think DroidStack is the best of the ones I tested so far.

The problem is, that writing to any SE-site is (currently) not allowed via API, only via webinterface. Writesupport is planned for API-version 3.0, and will be bound to other reputationlevels then via web as stated in "[Announcing API version 1.1](https://stackapps.com/questions/1999/announcing-api-version-1-1)" on [StackApps.com](https://stackapps.com/)?

Comment: I viewed this answer with DroidStack and written this line with opera mini.

Comment: Cool, how did you log in with OperaMini? Everytime I try to get to the log-in site with it, it tells me to enable JavaScript from external sites... Same problem with Opera Mobile when in "Turbo"-mode...

Comment: I am using latest opera mini with default configuration. Opera Mini is a lot faster than opera mobile on 2G network

Answer (score 2):

[Stack Exchange](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin) app is there in google play. You can ask question using this app.