# Android App for StackExchange

Tags: applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any app for Stack Exchange?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/338/is-there-any-app-for-stack-exchange)

Is there an android app for StackExchange sites and if not is there one in development?

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude, but did you even attempt to search or look at the "similar questions list" when you asked this? I just used the "Ask Question" button and typed in your exact title and the duplicate was literally at the top of the similar questions list.

Answer (score 4):

I know of 3, there may be more: I found these on [stackapps](https://stackapps.com/search?q=android).

[DroidStack](https://stackapps.com/questions/585/droidstack-for-android-now-with-chat-support)
[Stack Remote](https://stackapps.com/questions/3178/stack-remote-free-android-app-dedicated-towards-stack-exchange-sites)
[StackAnywhere](https://stackapps.com/questions/2370/stackanywhere-a-stack-exchange-client-for-android)

None of these apps really allow you to "login" and you can't ask or answer questions. This is probably a limitation of the StackExchange API. It also doesn't allow you to vote (since you are not logged in).

Comment: The current version of Stack Exchange API (v1.1) is read-only: http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage

Comment: the sooner the better