# Should the Droidstack application still work on my Android device?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I use the [Droidstack tool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.droidstack) as recommended on [some answers from this forum](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/338/is-there-any-app-for-stack-exchange/342#342). I haven't launched it for some time but I tried it again this week now it seems to be incapable of accessing the data. Is this an isolated issue or this application is now deprecated ? Perhaps a change in the API for StackExchange caused it ?

Thanks.

Comment: You should use the official app. SE's API is outside the scope of Android, you might ask on Meta Stack Exchange if you're interested in API details.

Comment: My interest in reality was more about the app than the API so I updated it in hope that it becomes more relevant.

Comment: The app has been removed from the Play Store so it definitely seems deprecated.

Comment: I'm just wondering why you are saying that it was removed ? The link to it included in my question still works.

Comment: I assume you are signed in to the Play Store?  It probably shows it because you have it installed.  I get `We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server.`

Comment: You are right I'm logged-in and I never realized that this was the behavior of Google Play. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the Droidstack application was actually removed from Google Play, therefore we can assume it is now deprecated.